Does Codepush work on Rive Files in React Native?
In react native, I am not able to do codepush on rive files. The Rive documentation does not say anything about Codepush. I tried sending a codepush of my react native code involving a rive file. But, the codepush bundle does not include the rive file. Does anyone know if codepush can be done on rive?
